# How can I open a TCP port in Raspberry Pi

Tags: tcp, command, raspberry-pi2

I have a Raspberry pi and I would like open a TCP port on it for example port : 11000
I tried to find a command in the internet for doing this but I could not.
I would be thankful if some body help me in this matter

thanks !

Comment: Depends of the port timelife but netstat can do this.
For exemple, in case of a listener socket : 

netstat -l localhost port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest digging into the ins and outs of networking since there are many options and you will need to be aware of the security implications with opening up your ports to the world. IP addresses are scanned every minute of every hour of every day so be very careful.

This is a simple example using netcat (nc) on the Bash shell. Below are two (2) nodes; my Raspberry Pi 2, and one of my Ubuntu servers; which is on the same network. Both nodes don't have any open ports except for SSH.

However, you'll see how easy it is to pass information from the Ubuntu server to the Pi without authentication.

So... the Pi opens (listens) on port 11000 and sends incoming data into file capture.this.  Then Ubuntu server echos a message to the Pi's LAN IP address at port 11000.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $  nc -lp 11000 > capture.this

david@ubuntuserver002:~$ echo "Hey, What's up Cuz!" | nc 10.100.71.141 11000

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat capture.this
Hey, What's up Cuz\!
```